# Getting std::bad_alloc error within Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am using a Shiny web server within a virtual machine and it is throwing a strange error since a few days. Other apps within the machine work fine.

The error messages within the specific loge files are

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:33017
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
```

or

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36529
SEND {"busy":"busy"}
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

How can I approach this problem? I can not reproduce the problem on my local machine, since it is running normally. How can I debug something like this?

The Webinterface just greys out and ask to reload: https://butterlab.imb-mainz.de/flydev/